# Good source for studying professional software development with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, project-management

I spent a lot of time reading blogs and tutorials on the Net regarding how to do this and that with VS2010, but I thought it would be better to learn it in a more systematic way.

Do you know of a good website/book that will teach me how to use Visual Studio 2010/2008 Team System + Microsoft Project to perform various tasks from Project Management to code development and testing in the way the software was designed for?

Thank you.

Comment: I would look into the various course books Microsoft offers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the ad I'm seeing to the right at this very moment:

http://ads.stackoverflow.com/a.aspx?Task=Click&ZoneID=4&CampaignID=854&AdvertiserID=200&BannerID=1469&SiteID=1&RandomNumber=1794578319&Keywords=visual-studio-2010%2cproject-management%2cx-user-highrep%2cx-user-registered

Comment: I'd say take that recommendation with a big grain of salt unless the poster has actually read this book.  Wrox copy is often chock full of pages and pages of garbage -- their MO seems to be to get books out first with the most number of pages, with the most number of authors.  And the quality of the prose often reflects that.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. The book reviews look good enough, but I'll leave it open for a while to see if there's any other interesting suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the supplier ;o) Microsoft has a nice section dedicated to [Visual Studio 2010 and .NET Framework 4 Training](http://channel9.msdn.com/learn/courses/vs2010/)